# Sending text from my EditText field to my WCF

Tags: android, wcf, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to send text from an editText to my WCF. It seems to work good most of the time, but when I write for example: "Hello" and then press enter on the keyboard and continues to write something I get an error: IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character at index 156. Wich is when i pressed enter on the keyboard.
(the whole process works when I dont use the enterbutton)

I still want my EditText to be multilined.

What can I do to be able to send my text to my wcf when an user have been typing something that contains an enterclick?

Can I remove the enterbutton and replace it with "Next" och "Done"?

I have tried to replace it with

```
invoiceText = invoiceText.replace("/n", "//n");
```

But with no success.

My editText:

```
        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/InputTextTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top|left" >
</EditText>
```

This is how I connect / write to my WCF: (This is RegisterTime in _phoneDAL)

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL + "/RegisterTime?userName=" + userName +  "&customerId=" + customerID + "&timeInvoiced=" + timeInvoice + "&timeWorked=" + timeWork + "&date=" + date + "&invoiceText=" + invoiceText);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        InputStream stream = httpEntity.getContent();

        String result = converter(stream);

        Log.v("Result registerTime", result);

        if(result != "-1" && result != "0"){
            return true;
        }
```

---

```
_phoneDAL.registerTime(id, timeDiffWorkTime, Integer.parseInt(_userName), selectedCustomer, timeDiffInvoiced, selectedDate, description);
```

Comment: Holy crap, now i feel so stupid :-) And by the way.. it worked when I changed it. Thanks Man! .. /Facepalm